# Occasional MongoTimeoutException when connecting to a replica set

Tags: java, mongodb, amazon-web-services, timeout, replicaset

I'm experiencing occasional `com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException` errors on AWS when connecting to a replica set. I'm connecting using the domain name that's being outputed from `rs.status()`, for example, `mongo1.production` and `mongo2.production` but I still get the timeouts.

My code looks like:

```
MongoClientOptions options = new MongoClientOptions.Builder()
                    .writeConcern(WriteConcern.ACKNOWLEDGED)
                    .readPreference(ReadPreference.primaryPreferred())
                    .connectTimeout(30000)
                    .socketTimeout(60000)
                    .connectionsPerHost(50)
                    .threadsAllowedToBlockForConnectionMultiplier(10)
                    .build();

List<ServerAddress> seeds = new ArrayList<ServerAddress>();
seeds.add(new ServerAddress("mongo1.production:27017"));
seeds.add(new ServerAddress("mongo2.production:27017"));
MongoClient client = new MongoClient(seeds, null, options);
```

Comment: Can you provide a full stack trace, including the root cause of the MongoTimeoutException?  Also, please provide the Java driver version and the server version.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to run mongo from Terminal by typing...

```
mongod
```

...you will (probably) get the following error:

```
*********************************************************************
 ERROR: dbpath (/data/db) does not exist.
 Create this directory or give existing directory in --dbpath.
 See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/startingandstoppingmongo
*********************************************************************
```

All you have to do is to create the directory/path that mongo is looking for (/data/db) like this:

```
sudo mkdir -p /data/db/
```

and then:

```
sudo chown `id -u` /data/db
```

Alternatively and as mentioned in the error message, you can give an existing directory in --dbpath like this:

```
mongod --dbpath /srv/mongodb/
```

For more details check the [MongoDB manual](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/#specify-a-data-directory).